# Product Image Settings not saving woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having an issue with the image resolution of Woocommerce product resolution settings.

Basically I am trying to change the image size for the product page on Woocommerce settings as the quality is complete rubbish.

For some reason the settings do not stay: the minute I refresh it, it goes back to default. It could be a database issue as I updated woocommerce yesterday.

Is there any php file I could write that would override the settings that do not save in Woocommerce?

The link to a particular product is here to give an example:
https://www.gogadgets.ie/shop/android-tv-boxes/mx3-android-quad-core/

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!! In my theme file I edited "functions.php". It turned out that the theme was overriding the Woocommerce settings in the database.

I changed the lines of code:

```
add_image_size( 'product-large', 624, 468, $hard_crop ); */ CHANGED HERE
add_image_size( 'product-medium', 246, 186, $hard_crop );
add_image_size( 'product-small', 194, 143, $hard_crop );
add_image_size( 'product-thumbnail', 73, 73, $hard_crop );

update_option( 'shop_single_image_size', array( 'width' => '624', 'height' => '468', 'crop' => $hard_crop ) );  */ CHANGED HERE
update_option( 'shop_catalog_image_size', array( 'width' => '246', 'height' => '186', 'crop' => $hard_crop ) ); 
update_option( 'shop_thumbnail_image_size', array( 'width' => '73', 'height' => '73', 'crop' => $hard_crop ) );
```